# Passing external $_SESSION values into CakePHP framework [CakePHP 4.x]

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am hoping to pass this external `$_SESSION['raw']` value from `mydomain.com/` into a CakePHP framework located in `mydomain.com/cake`.

In CakePHP cookbook https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/sessions.html, it says I need to configure the session base path to root to allow the session to persist across all subdomains, so I did this in `config/app.php`:

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_path' => '/',
        'session.cookie_domain' => '.mydoamin.com',
        'session.cookie_secure' => false
    ],
],
```

However as I tested it in the controller it returns empty (i.e. `[]`).

```
public function add()
{
    session_start();
    debug($_SESSION);

    // other code
}
```

Debugger:

```
APP/Controller/RecordingsController.php (line 53)
[
]
```

The `$_SESSION['raw']` value is accessible outside the CakePHP framework so I suspect I haven't set the base path right or there is another reason this isn't working..

Comment: As I recall, by default Cake also uses a different name for the session cookie. That would need to match in order to read a session created by other code.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Luckily that was removed in 4.x, so it should use the PHP defaults now, unless explicitly configured otherwise. However it still needs to match the cookie name used by the other application, so the question is, what settings does the other application use?

Comment: ps. never access supergobals like `$_SESSION` in CakePHP directly, always use the abstracted interfaces that the framework provides!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, even though it is not good practice at all, the $_SESSION was indeed passed into the framework. All you need to do is close the browser and open it again.